# Como pegar o nome do host em URLs?

Tags: php, string, url

Como pegar o nome do *host* de uma URL como o Mega, 4shared entre outros com PHP?

No caso gostaria de saber tendo este URL como exemplo:

> https://mega.co.nz/#!4090kJrY!LZiZBgsOo_Gg1sLnykZLHsUThAC9oaPRG3---0gD92Y

Como posso pegar deste URL somente a palavra `MEGA` descartando todo o resto?

Achei este tipo de código na internet a qual pega o nome do host só que não faz o que eu quero pois deixa ainda o *www* e o domínio eu só quero deixar o nome do host.

```
$host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
echo $host;
```

Comment: Então explique melhor o que deseja. Separe mais o texto para ele ficar mais claro, dê algum exemplo, mostre o que fez e o que está errado. Tenha certeza que está usando os termos corretos, se está citando a situação que a informação é obtida adequadamente. http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: pronto espero que agora você entenda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode obter esse valor manipulando o HTML, veja:

```
$contextOptions = array(
    "ssl"=>array(
        "verify_peer" => false,
        "verify_peer_name" => false,
    ),
); 

$url = file_get_contents("https://mega.co.nz/#!4090kJrY!LZiZBgsOo_Gg1sLnykZLHsUThAC9oaPRG3---0gD92Y", false, stream_context_create($contextOptions));

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($url);

$title = $dom->getElementsByTagName('title');

print($title->item(0)->nodeValue . "\n"); // MEGA
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/ftbP9T)</kbd>

Comment: no caso com esse código se for colocado esta URL https://mega.co.nz/#!4090kJrY!LZiZBgsOo_Gg1sLnykZLHsUThAC9oaPRG3---0gD92Y vai aparecer somente a palavra mega no print ?

Comment: Grato pela ajuda de todos o 2 código funcionou da forma que eu queria no caso ele verifica a existência do host primeiro certo ? caso exista não da valor falso ne e conclui colocando só o nome do host no caso mega.

Answer (score 5):

Talvez o que você queira seja isto:

```
<?php
$url = 'https://mega.co.nz/#!4090kJrY!LZiZBgsOo_Gg1sLnykZLHsUThAC9oaPRG3---0gD92Y';
$array_url = parse_url($url);
print_r($array_url);
echo parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST) . "\n"; //pega o HOST
echo $array_url['host'] . "\n"; //aqui pega só o HOST também.
$dominio = explode(".", parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST));
echo $dominio[0];
?>
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/qb5NFR). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/GetHostName). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/IO/GetHostName.php).

[Documentação da função](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php).

Comment: no caso com esse código se for colocado esta URL https://mega.co.nz/#!4090kJrY!LZiZBgsOo_Gg1sLnykZLHsUThAC9oaPRG3---0gD92Y vai aparecer somente a palavra mega no echo ? E caso tenha www como ficaria ?

Comment: O que eu tinha postado não pegaria só isto, eu fiz uma modificação para pegar. Mas note que é uma forma bem tosca. Ela funciona em situação bem específica. É muito difícil pegar o que você quer. Tem muitas regras que precisam ser observadas. Teria que ter uma tabela de todos os [TLDs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-level_domain) para verificar se o que vem antes de um deles é o domínio que você quer. Não tenho a [RFC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Request_for_Comments) aqui mas acho que nem isto é suficiente para garantir o resultado.

Comment: ok já entendi tendo no caso os nomes de referencia daria pra fazer uma busca com precisão certo ? se eu colocar eles na SQL teria como fazer isso buscando uma comparação entre o nome e a URL pegando somente o nome especifico.

Comment: Sim, com informação suficiente poderia.

Comment: Obrigada pela sua ajuda.